# Docker get real-time logs of one of the tasks of a service

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-swarm

I can't `ssh` into docker manager and get service logs. I get `"docker service logs" requires exactly 1 argument.` error, when I `ssh` into my manager with

```
docker-machine ssh manager1
```

and run

```
docker logs --follow $(docker ps | grep redis |  head -n1 | cut -d " " -f1)
```

everything works, but when I run the following command I get `"docker service logs" requires exactly 1 argument.`

```
docker-machine ssh manager1 "docker service logs $(docker ps | grep redis |  head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f1) --follow"
```

how can I `ssh` into manager1 and pass the command to run?

Comment: try to avoid `docker logs --follow $(docker ps | grep redis |  head -n1 | cut -d " " -f1)` as you can name your container and filter with a more reliable name see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/ and `--filter , -f   Filter output based on conditions provided`

Answer (score 0):

[`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps) has some [filtering](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering) and output [options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#options) that mean awk/grep etc are rarely needed.

```
docker-machine ssh manager1 sh -uexc 'echo; 
  cid=$(docker ps -q -f ancestor=redis -l); 
  docker service logs -f $cid || echo cid[$cid]'
```

`docker ps` options.

```
--filter , -f       Filter output based on conditions provided
--format            Pretty-print containers using a Go template
--last , -n         Show n last created containers (includes all states)
--latest , -l       Show the latest created container (includes all states)
```

Comment: running this command, I staill get the same error `"docker service logs" requires exactly 1 argument.`

Comment: Tune the `docker ps` on it's own command until it outputs the correct id

Comment: You probably need `docker service ps` in any case?